# how to grant workspace admins permission to connect storage accounts powerBI

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, storage, azure-storage-account

I'm the Admin and i made the account. Also, i already made a Dataset. Now i want to connect that dataset to a Storage Account in Azure but unfortunately I'm not able to do it, as you can see there's no button.

> Ask your tenant admin to grant workspace admins permission to connect storage accounts

i suppose i am the Tenant Admin.

how can i connect/make a dataset from a CSV or a file in Storage account (Azure Data Lake Gen 2).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dialog is for using your ADLS storage account as the location for your Data Flows.  If you just want to load data from Azure Storage into a DataSet you don't need to do that.  Just configure the connection in Power Query.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/datalakestorage  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/azurestorage-blobs